# Unable to publish package to pub dev

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, package

I have been trying to publish my package on pub dev but I am always receiving this error:

```
Connection closed before full header was received
pub finished with exit code 69
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. I checked with the `--dry-run` command but there are no errors.

I don't know how to fix this issue please help.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same.

Comment: Yes there was some connection issue in some countries you can use vpn to publish the package.